# wordpress add_action problems ,woocommerce custom

Tags: wordpress

I just have a little question, I want to understand something in this code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' ,   
  'custom_woocommerce_before_cart_shop', 10, 2 );
```

What does `10, 2` mean here?

Answer (score 1):

from the wordpress [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)

```
<?php add_action( $hook, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args ); ?>
```

> priority is used to specify the order in which the functions
>   associated with a particular action are executed. Lower numbers
>   correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same
>   priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the
>   action. (the default value is 10 )
>
> accepted_args are the number of arguments the hooked function accepts.
>   In WordPress 1.5.1+, hooked functions can take extra arguments that
>   are set when the matching do_action() or apply_filters() call is run.
>   For example, the action comment_id_not_found will pass any functions
>   that hook onto it the ID of the requested comment.

If u know what a hooks is in wordpress this is really simple to understand but here would be an example:

```
function echo_comment_id( $comment_id ) {
   echo 'Comment ID ' . $comment_id . ' could not be found';
}
add_action( 'comment_id_not_found', 'echo_comment_id', 10, 1 );
```

The args are used mainly when you use the do_action function

```
<?php do_action( $tag, [$arg1, $arg2, ...] ); ?>
```

you just use the "tag" associated to the hook and the args passed to it.

Looking on internet I couldn't find the `custom_woocommerce_before_cart_shop` function, so, just search it on woocomerce code, it should be a function with 2 arguments.